# Jquery UI dialog with parameters issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am trying to pass parameters to Jquery UI dialog for the new page. The new page has Page_Load method which connects to the database and displays the data. I am having issue with Page_Load method getting called first before $(document).ready. So parameter is empty.  I appreciate any suggestions.

MainPage.aspx:

```
        function ShowGraph(sId) {
              var oid = sId;
             $("#dialog")
               .load('Graph.aspx')
              .data("sId", sId)

             $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        }

<div id="dialog" title="My Dialog Title">
</div>
```

### Graph.aspx:

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                    $get('<%= HiddenId.ClientID %>').value = $("#dialog").data('sId');
            });

  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="HiddenId"></asp:HiddenField>
```

### code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BL.GetNumbers(HiddenId.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass parameter in query string like

```
function ShowGraph(sId) {
              var oid = sId;
             $("#dialog")
               .load('Graph.aspx?sId='+sId)

             $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        }
```

and on page load event you can get it.